# What do SLD text symbolizers label when you have both a point symbolizer and a line symbolizer in a rule?

Tags: geotools

I am building a JavaFX renderer for shape files and a "point of ambiguity" has come up around text symbolizers.

I have an SLD feature type style for a feature type T as follows (abstracting from all the XML):

```
Rule
    Filter 
    PointSymbolizer
    LineSymbolizer
    TextSymbolizer
```

If a feature f satisfies the filter, we:

- run the point symbolizer with f
- run the line symbolizer with f

My question is: when the text symbolizer is run are we labeling the point from the point symbolizer, or the line from the line symbolizer? Or even both?

I **think** the answer to my question is that the `TextSymbolizer` must contain a `LabelPlacement` element, and the `LabelPlacement` element in turn must contain exactly one of a `PointPlacement` or `LinePlacement`, and that tells us whether we are labeling with respect to the point or the line. Is that correct?

If it is correct then there is a follow on issue -- if the rule looks like this:

```
Rule
    Filter 
    LineSymbolizer
    LineSymbolizer
    TextSymbolizer
         LabelPlacement
             LinePlacement
```

Then is the text symbolizer labelling both lines?

thx
g

Answer (score 0):

It (like all symbolizers) will use the default geometry of the feature unless you specify a particular geometry by the Geometry tag.

For your 2nd question there's only one line not two.

Comment: Re using the default geometry, I see know. Makes perfect sense. For the second question, I am not sure I understand why there is only one line, as I have two line symbolizers ...

Comment: Each line symbolizer draws the same line, there is only one line in the feature

Comment: [I am not being critical here - just trying to understand how to render features] Both line symbolizers could use different properties from the feature being rendered to create different lines. e.g. one symbolizer creates a line of width 1 and the other of width 100. If the text symbolizer specifies the label should go along the line, then the label can go in one of two positions?. If they were point symbolizers each could use a different mark size again giving different possible locations for the label from the text symbolizer? I guess I am misunderstanding something fundamental here ...

Comment: All the symbolizers are working with the same line, how it is rendered is unknown to the next symbolizers. So the textsymbolizer doesn't know about anything but the line in the feature. Have you looked at the existing renderer implementation to see how they do it

Comment: Ah, "working with the same line" means the line in real/map coordinates, not the rendered line? If that's the case then that's probably the thing I am missing. It also means that if you want to show text along a line, and the line is rendered thick by the line symbolizer, the thickness "definition" in the line symbolizer has to be somehow "repeated" in the text symbolizer to correctly position the text? And yes I have looked at existing implementations, but implementations are not specifications defining what should happen.

Comment: Yes, that's right